# Using Jekyll with Github webhooks for automated deployment

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, deployment

I'm a designer and want to serve some static sites with Jekyll.

So I grabbed a VPS (ubuntu 12.04) and installed nginx, ruby and jekyll.

I work from a few different computers throughout the day, so I wanted to use GitHub for ease of its client. Hence I installed git, php5fpm(fastcgi) and set up two basic scripts, one for handling the webhook (`webhook.php`) and one for compiling and deploying the site (`build.sh`)

---

With some help, I was able to progress to the point that I can run the build script, but the build script stops when running the Jekyll command and throws an error saying:

```
bash: command not found
```

That is not the case when running my regular user, so I'm thinking this has something to do with the `.bash_profile` of the user running the nginx workers (which is `www-data`).

So to summarize, my question is: How can I make the Jekyll command available to the `www-data` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make Jekyll available to `www-data` user.
A cleaner and better approach will be this:

1. Create a new user, dedicated to running your Jekyll site

   - Make Jekyll available to this user, test that it has everything it needs
2. Create a virtual host, dedicated to running your Jekyll site

   - Make it to run as the new dedicated user
   - Make its document root owned by the new dedicated user

This setup should be easier to test, debug and replicate, and more secure too.